# Merging two active (distinct) domains

Tags: seo, domains, ranking

I'm an SEO rookie.  My company has two websites.  One for the main company, and one for a recruiting aspect of that company.  Normally I'd say the recruiting content should have been a sub-directory under the parent site.  However, what we currently have is 2 distinct root domains.

Both sites get similar levels of traffic (~2-3K page views per day).  Is it wise or unwise to consider merging the two domains at this point?

Comment: It has been my long standing opinion that dividing content over multiple domains is to divide potential amongst amungst entities without any one being able to reach full potential. Make it one domain, the one that represents the brand best.

Answer (score 1):

There is not an easy answer. We should run some tests to know which is the best solution but with the information you have provided, that's what I would do:

- Report of relevant keywords and traffic generated in each site
- Analysis of how we could merge the best keywords in one site (structure, migration, etc)
- Leave the second domain to rank for secondary keywords
- Internal and external link strategy among both domains

So in the end, I'll have:

- Main site with the most relevant keywords (including brand)
- A second site with alternative/secondary keywords